# Load same sidebar multiple times

Tags: sidebar

I came across a very different scenario where I had to use `get_sidebar('recommendations')` multiple times on one page. But it works only one time.

It works multiple times only when I use `include('sidebar-recommendations.php')` but I want to go with standardize way in WordPress.

I searched in the code but couldn't find the reason why It doesn't work multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

get_template() function has a protection against this.

You will have to use include().

Comment: I would suggest using `get_template_part( 'sidebar', 'recommendations' )`, as you still keep the core WordPress functionality for hooks & child themes.

Answer (score 0):

get_template_part( 'sidebar', 'recommendations' ) 
is fine and mostly in use by popular themes ie. "Enfold"
Thanx for suggestion @Klian

Comment: Please wrap your inline code in [»backticks«](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm) to format is as such. Further I think, your answer could also been a comment to the answer from Klian as it does not really provide new information.

Comment: Downvoted because of formatting? This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have an other option as well if it is important to use one sidebar in template more than once, why not to use jQuery and clone that sidebar and by using once and appending that to specific section, but it is important not to use idz in sidebar because multiplications of idz is not valid and may cause layout breakage